# Position the checkable button of a checkable menu item in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, layout

This is how my menu looks like right now:
[image]

As you can see, the checkable buttons for Top 10/Top 25 are below the Text. I want them to be right to the Text, in the same line.
How do I pull that off?

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuFree"
    android:title="Free Apps" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuPaid"
    android:title="Paid Apps" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuSongs"
    android:title="Songs" />
<group
    android:id="@+id/menugroupLimit"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu10"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="Top 10" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu25"
        android:title="Top 25" />
</group>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuRefresh"
    android:title="Refresh" />
```

Comment: Is that image from the preview screen in Android Studio? If I throw that menu into an app and try it on a Pixel, it looks correct. It may be that it's just an issue in the Android Studio renderer.

Comment: oh my, thank you. You are right.
Now I feel golly stupid.
Still, is there a way to change the position manually?

Comment: There are some overrides for providing your own element. I haven't done it, but if you look around, you will probably find a few examples.